# How do I add laptop to DC through wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, windows-server-2012, windows-domain

I have a desktop running a few VMs, one which is a domain controller. I'm wondering if there's anyway for my laptop to connect to the domain controller over wifi? Is what I'm looking for possible?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, the configuration depends on what you are using to run your VMs but you should be able to bridge the networks. Even if that is not possible you may be able to get it working with NAT although that's a little more difficult.

Comment: I'm using HyperV on Server2012R2 and the laptop is running the same thing.

Comment: I second the vote to bridge the networks, as long as the OS instance is on the same logical network as the server the OS will connect to the Domain Controller.  Your computer and the domain controller don't care about how the network is physically setup.

Comment: So my network on the desktop is already bridged and looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/lpaOEDu.png  I'm just not sure how to proceed on the laptop side of things

Comment: What is the IP address of the laptop & DC? Can you ping between them or otherwise reach each other over your network? Once that works you just need to add your laptop to the domain using domain credentials.

Comment: The desktop has two switches though, ones for internal communication and the other internet access. I can ping the desktop from the laptop using it's name and it'll return IP 192.168.1.7 but i'm guessing these are just IPs temporarely given out by the router. On the internal NIC I have the DC set to 10.0.0.1

Comment: You have to set it up so the laptop can see the VM running the domain controller. You need to bridge (have the VM look like it's on the "real" network) instead of NAT (have the VM be proxied to the real network but have a RFC 1918 address)